# Wordpress /wp-admin keeps reloading

Tags: wordpress, malware

I have a wordpress website which is shared hosting to my other websites in bluehosts, there's a time that when I visit my /wp-admin it keeps reloading, after closing it and leaving it for several minutes or an hour it is working properly, but then it'll keep reloading after several minutes of using it.

Does anyone knows what seems to be the problem?

I'm always trying to reach out to bluehost but it seems they can't resolve it, they just clear the cache from the server.
I also try to clear cache from my browser
I also try to check my ftp for possible malware.